# Is there a module to assemble configuration files, support Jinja2 templating, and also remove an entry when a source template is removed?

Tags: ansible

While working with Ansible modules, More notably `assemble` and `blockinfile`, I've noticed a few drawbacks to both modules. It could be lack of education on either module, or an intentional design.

## Assemble

For example, when working with `assemble`, I can read in a directory of files, and 'assemble' them into one configuration file, like so:

```
  assemble:
    src: <path to directory of files>
    dest: <destination>
```

The result is expected, one configuration file comprised of all files included in `src`. However, when using variables, they are not expanded. Which is also expected. I could use a `lookup`, which would expand these variables, however I am unaware of such a lookup that would include one directory for use with `assemble`.

## Blockinfile

When working with `blockinfile`, I can use `lookup` to expand variables in my source file.

```
  blockinfile:
    create: yes
    block: "{{ lookup('template', '<path to file>') }}"
    dest: <destination>
    marker: "# {mark} Test "
    backup: yes
```

I could also include multiple files like this:

```
  blockinfile:
    create: yes
    block: "{{ lookup('template', \"<path>/{{ item }}\") }}"
    dest: <destination>
    marker: "# {mark} Test {{ item }}"
    backup: yes
  with_items:
    - file1.j2
    - file2.j2
```

However the drawback with this solution would be that if a source template file is removed, it is not removed from the file specified in `dest`.

### The End Goal

The goal that I would like to achieve would appear as

- Read in a directory of files, and assemble them into one file.
- Support for variables. When `{{ variable }}` is in the source file, have it expand to its value
- When one or more source files is absent after previously adding it into the destination file, have it removed from the destination file. Also have the state report as `changed`.

Comment: You can do this with a template module to create *temp files*, and then use the assemble module to stitch all the temp files together (using `remote_src=true`) and finally delete the temp files. Not sure if there's a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response, That's a good approach to this problem, I almost forgot about the presence of `remote_src`. I'll try a few different methods using this.

Comment: Could I ask you to report back what you found? I haven't experienced this situation yet, but it's a matter of time and I would like to know how to deal with it :D. Much appreciated!

Comment: We ended up using `blockinfile` to construct multiple files inside a temporary directory on the remote server, and then `assemble` with `remote_src` set to `true`, pointing to the temporary directory. After the file is assembled, the temporary directory is removed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a main template that include others templates.

[Jinja documentation for include](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#include)

An exemple of `main.j2`:

```
My first block
{% include block1.j2 %}

My second block
{% include block2.j2 %}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, However this goes against the last required goal :
`When one or more source files is absent after previously adding it into the destination file, have it removed from the destination file. Also have the state report as changed`

Comment: `{% includeblock1.j2 ignore missing %}`